# Array of strings to a formatted string

Tags: java

I've tried to create a method that takes in an array of strings and returns a single formatted string.
The last word should be separated by the word 'and' instead of a comma.

But it doesn't work as expected :) 
It doesn't replace the last comma by the word "and".
Can you please advise where is my mistake.

thanks.

```
public class Kata {
    public static String formatWords(String[] words) {
        List<String> words1 = Arrays.asList(words);
        ListIterator<String> wordIter = words1.listIterator();
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();

        while (wordIter.hasNext()) {
            out.append(wordIter.next());

            if (wordIter.hasNext()) {
                out.append(",");
            }
        }

        return out.toString().replaceAll(",$", "and");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by *doesn't work as expected*

Comment: it doesn't replace the last comma to word "and"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you may have empty items, first use a list to clear the empty items:

```
public static String formatWords(String[] words) {
    if (words == null)
        return "";

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String word : words) {
        word = word.trim();
        if (!word.isEmpty())
            list.add(word);
    }

    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();

    int len = list.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        out.append(list.get(i));
        if (i == len - 2)
            out.append(" and ");
        else if (i < len - 2)
            out.append(",");
    }

    return out.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] array = {"", "apples", "", "oranges", "", "melons", ""};
    System.out.println(formatWords(array));
}
```

will print:

```
apples,oranges and melons
```

Comment: thanks for the code. i tried to modify your code in order to ignore empty string cases (like ` {"", "", "three"}` to return only "three"). I've extended the statement `else if (i < words.length - 2 && words.length>3 && words[i]!=null)` but still cannot pass the test

Answer (score 0):

I'd iterate up to the before-last element and concat the strings with commas, and then concat the last one with an "and":

```
public static String formatWords(String[] words) {
   // Handle nulls and empty arrays
   if (words == null || words.length) {
        return "";
    }

    // Handle the first word
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(words[0]);

    // Handle all the words from the second to the before last
    for (int i = 1; i < words.lengh - 1; ++i) {
        sb.append(", ").append(word[i]);
    }

    // Check that there are at least two words
    if (words.length > 1) {
        // Handle the last word with an "and"
        sb.append(" and ").append(words[1])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`replaceAll(",$", "and");` doesn't do what you think. It cannot find the last `,` in the string.

Try this

```
while(wordIter.hasNext()) {
    //your code

}

if (words.length > 1) {
    int indexOfLastComma = out.length() - words[words.length - 1].length();
    return out.replace(indexOfLastComma - 1, indexOfLastComma, " and ").toString();
}
return out.toString();
```

We find the index of the last Comma and then replace it with `and` in its place.

---

Here's a fun way using Streams

```
String tempResult = IntStream.range(0, words.length - 1)
        .mapToObj(i -> words[i])
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
return words.length > 1 ? tempResult + " and " + words[words.length - 1] : words[0];
```

**EDIT:**

To filter out empty words, you can use a filter. Now checking `words.length > 1` at the end will no longer work (since it can have empty strings). So, I'm checking if the `tempResult` has atleast one `,`.

Here is a complete solution

```
String tempResult = Arrays.stream(words)
       .filter(word -> !word.isEmpty())
       .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
int indexOfLastComma = tempResult.lastIndexOf(',');
return indexOfLastComma != -1 ? tempResult.substring(0, indexOfLastComma) + " and "
        + tempResult.substring(indexOfLastComma + 1): tempResult;
```

It creates substring - so not the most efficient solution.

Comment: really nice and compact solution using Stream. is it possible to modify the code you have provided in order to cover empty string cases. for example ` {" ", " ", "three"} `to return `three`. I've tried but without result till now

Comment: @JonMark See my edit. Note: This will return an empty string if the array is empty or has only empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use List and ListIterator (in this case!)
this is my solution!

ps: I don't undestand why the method is Static, i think in this casa is not necessary because we don't work on any static variables.

```
public static String formatWords(String[]words){

    //Usefull to build the final resoult
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 

    /*start to put the word in the string builder
    from the first to the last*/
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

        //put the wordat position i in string builder
        sb.append(words[i]);

        /*if the word is the 2 last and there are egual or more than 
        2 elements in words array
        we can add the "and"*/
        if(i==words.length-2 && words.length>=2) { 
            sb.append(" and "); 

         /*if the word is not the last put a comma
         (actually we put a comma when there are more thand 3 item in words, but not in the last)
         */   
        }else if(i<words.length-1 ){ 
            sb.append(", ");  
        }

        /*if word[i] is the last of the array words we don't use nobody of the if!*/

        /*this code word on 0 1,2,3 ore more word in array words!*/
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```